# D3 (with angular) Failing to insert a span inside a div

Tags: d3.js

I have this working [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xKfoC). where the d3 part is basically:

```
var bar = chart.append("div").attr("class", "chart")
             .selectAll('div')
            .data(scope.data.sort().reverse()).enter().append("div")
             .transition().ease("elastic")
             .style("width", function(d) { return (d[0]/sum)*attrs.chartWidth + "px"; })//This is where I base the width as a precentage from the sum and calculate it according to the chart-width attribute
            .style("background-color",function(){i++;if (i<=colors.length-1){return colors[i-1]} else {return colors[(i-1)%colors.length]}}).text(function(d) { return d[1] ; })
```

but when I try to `append("span")` in the chaining so the text would be on the span and not in the parent div. the text just disappears and the dev console shows no clue of both the span and the text.  Also tried `insert("span")` and even replacing the `.text` for `.html(function(d){return "<span>"+d[1]+"</span>"}`

neither work.

any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting a [`transition`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) in the chain. The `transition` object provides many functions just like a normal [`d3.selection`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) including `.remove`, `.text` and `.html`, but does not allow `.append` operation.

You should re-factor the code to read:

```js
    var bar = chart.append("div").attr("class", "chart")
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(scope.data.sort().reverse()).enter().append("div");

    bar
        .transition().ease("elastic")
        .style("width", function(d) { return (d[0]/sum)*attrs.chartWidth + "px"; })//This is where I base the width as a precentage from the sum and calculate it according to the chart-width attribute
        .style("background-color",function(){i++;if (i<=colors.length-1){return colors[i-1]} else {return colors[(i-1)%colors.length]}}) }) 

    bar.append('span')
       .text(function(d) { return d[1] });
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepen.io/musically_ut/pen/qmKwB)

As a side note, while selecting the `background-color`, you do not need to maintain the index variable yourself, `d3` passes the data `d` and the index `i` to the setter function you provide to `.style`:

```js
.style("background-color",
       function(d, i){  // <-- 'd' and 'i' are passed by d3
            if (i<=colors.length-1)
                 {return colors[i-1]} 
            else {return colors[(i-1)%colors.length]}}) 
 })
```

Comment: Thanks! and also for the other tip